# Could this definition of a time-continuous Markov chain be slightly wrong?

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, stochastic-processes, definition, markov-chains

In a book I am reading these are the definitions of a time-continuous Markov chain.

> 1. It has a finite number, $N$ of states.
> 2. For arbitrary $j,k,s$ and $t$ with $s<t$, assume that $X_s=j$ and consider the probability $X_t=k$. This probability does not change if
>      information about the behaviour of the process during the interval
>      $[0,s)$ is added to the knowledge that $X_s=j$.
> 3. $\lim\limits_{t \downarrow s}P_{jk}(s,t)=\delta_{jk}$ for all $j,k, s \ge 0$where $\delta_{jk}$ is the Kronecker delta.
> 4. For all $j,k, j\ne k$ and all $t \ge 0$:
>
> $\mu_{jk}(t)=\lim\limits_{\Delta t \downarrow
>  0}\frac{P_{jk}(t,t+\Delta t)}{\Delta t}$,
>
> exits and is continuous in $t$.

I am wondering if instead of number $3$ it should be 
$\lim\limits_{s \uparrow t}P_{jk}(s,t)=\delta_{jk}$?

The reason I am wondering about this is that condition number $4$ already seems to imply condition number $3$? And the author has this comment after the conditions:

> By these four assumptions, it may be shown that for each $s\ge0$, each
>   $P_{jk}(s,\cdot)$ is continuous for all $t\ge s$. Similarly, for each
>   $t>0$, each $P_{jk}(\cdot,t)$ is continuous for all $s$ in the closed
>   interval [0,t].

I am not able to show this comment by the four conditions, only right continuity. But with the suggestion I posted above I am able to prove left-continuity.

What do you guys think? Is the definition wrong, and should it be modified?

Comment: 4 and the state space being finite implies 3, that doesn't make the definition wrong, just slightly redundant.

Comment: @Ian Yes I guess you could say that. But with the added comment about continuity is it still right?

Comment: The comment indeed follows from the given conditions; the only discontinuities are in the trajectory itself (and the trajectory is right-continuous, which is more or less a matter of convention).

Comment: @Ian Yes I am not talking about the continuity properties of the trajectories, but of the probabilities. Could you please be so kind to show left-continuity of the probabilities?, I am only able to show right-continuity.

Comment: It follows from #4, which says that the right hand derivative of $P_{jk}$ exists and is continuous everywhere, which gives the same for the left hand derivative.

Comment: @Ian What do you mean? There are examples of non-continuous functions with continuous right derivatives.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose a right-continuous piecewise constant function has that problem for instance. Maybe the conditions are indeed not sufficient...?